# DataGridView doesn't show data: DataSet is empty

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I've created one project and i've used L2S. So it was working fine.

So after i'm using same connection string and creating new WinForm project. I'm placing a datagrid, selecting this connection string. I'm selecting DataMember and rows headers appears. But when i'm starting an app, i'm watching locals and i see that DataSet has all tables empty. I suggested that they will auto-populate from DB, but they doesn't. So what should I do? DB is not empty.

P.S. I've googled, really.

So it really doesn't auto-populate. I have a table "Benefits". So i've writed

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadikDataSet.BenefitsDataTable benefitsDataTable = new BenefitsTableAdapter().GetData();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = benefitsDataTable;
}
```

and it works. So tnx. It's so stupid that I should manualy call it.

Comment: Post your code which is not working

Comment: I had no code, i just placed a DGW on form and did some steps using BindingWizard

Comment: Oh my gawd, I literally posted my answer at the very same time you edited your post. At least I had the right answer ;)

Comment: So it'an answer. I have no reason to not mark it as answer. Tnx anyway :)

Comment: You can do it in another topics, i have a problem with ADO.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a BindingSource? Make sure your assigning it in your form load event like so:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Bind the DataGridView to the BindingSource 
    // and load the data from the database.
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
    GetData("select * from Alex_db");
}
```

More detailed example [available here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 0):

I am not very good with L2S but you should try to add same DB connection again in your new project in place to adding it from old project.